# Streaming parquet files from S3 (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, streaming, parquet

I should begin by saying that this is *not* running in Spark.

What I am attempting to do is

- stream n records from a parquet file in S3
- process
- stream back to a different file in S3
  ...but am only inquiring about the first step.

Have tried various things like:

```
from pyarrow import fs
from pyarrow.parquet import ParquetFile

s3 = fs.S3FileSystem(access_key=aws_key, secret_key=aws_secret)
with s3.open_input_stream(filepath) as f:
    print(type(f))  # pyarrow.lib.NativeFile
    parquet_file = ParquetFile(f)
    for i in parquet_file.iter_batches():  # .read_row_groups() would be better
        # process
```

...but getting `OSError: only valid on seekable files` , and not sure how to get around it.

Apologies if this is a duplicate.  I searched but didn't find quite the fit I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`open_input_file`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.fs.S3FileSystem.html#pyarrow.fs.S3FileSystem.open_input_file) which 'Open an input file for random access reading.' instead of [`open_input_stream`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.fs.S3FileSystem.html#pyarrow.fs.S3FileSystem.open_input_stream) which 'Open an input stream for sequential reading.'

For context, in a parquet file the metadata is at the end so you need to be able to go back and forth in the file.

Comment: Ah.. yes!  thank you!  Did not even think to look there!